# Different Activity each tab fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 3 tabs, and I'm trying to **show a different activity and layout each tab**.
I am using the tabs as my app navigation, so when a has changed, the whole layout and activity need to be changed.

Actually only the layout is changing.

Since the MainActivity.java + layout has the PageAdapter in it (the PageAdapter is loading the tab's content),
I have moved my first page activity from the **MainActivity.java** to a new java activity called **showUpdates.java**. Now I'm trying to **access this activity as my Tab #1 content**.

If you still didn't understand what I'm asking for, The following will make it clear:

My 3 tabs are:

> Java: TabFragment1.java, XML: activity_show_updates.xml
>
> Java: TabFragment2.java, XML: tab_fragment_2.xml
>
> Java: TabFragment3.java, XML: tab_fragment_3.xml

The TabFragment1.java:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        /**
         * Was trying:
         * Intent intent = new Intent(...)
         * startActivity(intent);
         */
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_show_updates, container, false);
    }
```

As you can see, it's moving to a new layout, **activity_show_updates.xml.**

**What I'm trying to do is - using my showUpdates.java as the Activity of the tab_fragment_1.**

I've been trying to use Intent but my app crashed when I created it at **TabFragement1.java**.

Anyone knows how I can make showUpdates.java as the activity of this layout?

Comment: Are you sure you need a new activity for each page turn? You could accomplish what you need with fragments

Comment: How I can do it with fragments? I already have the java files of them (as shown above), but how do I implement my code as activity (with the onCreate) on the fragment java file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot nest activities. There are fragments for that. Just create a different fragment for each tab and use an Activity to hold all of them. If you need it, you can also create child fragments (although the support is not so good and you might have some problems, but nothing really hard to handle).

Comment: How do I implement the onCreate() and the rest of the action methods on the fragment java file I have created and shown above? I have updated my ListView  in the MainActivity.onCreate() before I was implementing the tabs, where do I update the ListView now?

Comment: just use onCreateView() method of the fragment. It's almost the same as in activities.

You can have better informations here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have viewpager working, you can do the following:

```
public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_ITEMS;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            if(position == 0){
                 //return first fragment
            }
           else if(position == 1){
                 //return second fragment
           }
...
    }
```

and you can do your onCreate logic in onCreateView:

```
public override View OnCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View yourFragment = inflater.inflate (Resource.Layout.fragment_name, container, false);
                ... //do stuff
              return yourFragment;
}
```

All you need to do is define which fragments to output in your adapter